# infopath: create a multiple selection tree manually

Tags: infopath2010

I was hoping that you could answer a query I have with Microsoft INFOPATH.

How could I design a multiple selection list , where each entry has subsequent multiple options and each one among those multiple options further leads to some more.

To put it in a more simple manner, it will have the features of a tree structure.

Also the selected entries (parent along with their child and their child shall be concatenated in a numbered list).I will also like to add that there are no interaction with database or sharepoint lists- I want to have the data manually fed.

Example - Suppose there are 10 countries in a list. On selection of any one, all the states/districts on it populates. Further on selection of any state,the cities inside it populates. At the end those are all listed in a numbered list somewhere.

Could this be done?

Comment: cross post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79907/infopath-create-multiple-selection-tree-manually -- please do not ask the same question on more than one StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this could be accomplished, I don't know the scope of what you need to do, but you *could* do it with conditional rules.

ddl "Country" (France, U.K., Germany, Italy, Spain)

You would have an additional ddl for each possible choice for country that is hidden through a rule, have it hidden unless it matches the value of "Country". So say you want to show cities in France, if the Country of France is selected you would have an additional rule on it that looks something like this...

if "Country" does not equal "France" hide+disable this control.

ddl "FranceCities" (Paris, Marseille, Lyon, Toulouse)
ddl "UKCities" (London, Bath, Birmingham, Lichfield)

Additionally it would be important to do testing and find out how it behaves if you select a street for "France" but realize you meant to select "Germany".

Hope that helps!

(Once again, I don't know the scope of what you need to do, so the best method for you could be something different.)